# Address of static member in a Class

Tags: c++, class, pointers, static, static-members

How to get memory address of a private static member of a class in C++.
In the below code I am accessing the private members of the class directly via their memory address.

```
#include <iostream>

class directM {
    int a;
    int b;
public:
    directM(int aa , int bb){
        a = aa;
        b = bb;
    }
    void show(){
        std::cout << a << b << std::endl;
    }
};

int main(){
    directM dm(10,20);
    dm.show();
    *(int*)( &dm ) = 15;
    *(int*)( ( (int*)(&dm) ) + 1 ) = 25;
    dm.show();
    return 0;
}
```

Now if I change one of the members and make it static i.e

`static int b;`

Now how would I be able to access this private member directly by its address.

Note:- I know this is a very unwise way to access the data and I am not using it to solve any problem. This is just a learning exercise to get to know the language better.

Comment: @NielsKeurentjes no that wouldn't work. The code is accessing a member via its offset from the start of the object, but a static variable is independent of the object.

Comment: Static members are not part of the object

Comment: Ah I didn't notice the nasty pointer arithmetic. That part obviously can't work, in any case. Deleted my previous comment, and kudos to @MarkRansom for writing it up as a concise and clear answer.

Comment: Under no circumstances should one ever take an offset from the object to access its member variables with. If you have a legitimate reason to access the variable directly via an address, the object should have a method to give you the address. That said, whatever problem is being solved here almost certainly has a better way, making the current question little more than mental masturbation.

Comment: This expression: `*(int*)( &dm ) = 15;` is not safe and depends upon specific undefined behaviour present in the compiler/platform.

Comment: What problem are you trying to solve?

Comment: @Alan not trying to solve any problem , this is just for learning purpose

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ideally, you shouldn't and the language is designed to make it hard because it's marked as `private`.

If you change it to a public static member (so you can access it by name) then you can use the `address-of` operator thusly:

```
class directM { public: static int b; }

int* staticMember = &directM::b;
```

C++ makes no guarantees of the in-memory layout or organisation of static members, so this code is unsafe:

```
class directM {
public:
    static int first;
    static int second;
}

int* firstAddr = &directM::first;
int* secondAddr = firstAddr++;
assert( secondAddr == &directM::second );
```

Answer (score 7):

Static member variables are not part of an object, their storage is completely independent. There's *no way* to know their location without accessing the variable name.